# Why does inner DIV spill out of outer DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have been long away from HTML and CSS, can't find the solution to this simple problem.

I have one div inside the other. Outer Black and inner orange.

[image]

My HTML and CSS is :

```css
#outer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: black;
}
#inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is my inner DIV spilling out of the outer ? How do I fix it without giving fixed dimensions?

Comment: Remove the margin from "#inner" and it won't overlap.

Comment: @cthefinal I wanted to have margin, thats why I added it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of the margin - the width is 100% PLUS the margin. To avoid that, write `width: calc(100% - 10px);` (= twice the margin.) Same for height.

```css
#outer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: black;
}
#inner {

  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

The answers above assume that you do not want the margin.  If you, in fact, want the margins, then you can add `overflow: hidden;` to the #outer.

Answer (score 3):

The margin property moves the div by 5 pixels from both top and left direction, and since divs have `overflow: show;` as default (which means any content that goes outside the div will be shown) you can see the div going outside.

you can avoid that using `overflow: hidden;` to hide any content going outside the div, if that's what you want to do otherwise you need to set your inner div size in a way that doesn't go outside its container

```
#outer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#inner {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `#inner` in position absolute and instead of using margin, you can use this

```
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  bottom:5px;
  left:5px;
  right:5px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

#outer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: black;
}
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  bottom:5px;
  left:5px;
  right:5px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely happening because your inner div is being pushed out of its parent by the margin. Have you tried setting 'inner' to position: absolute with left: 0 and top: 0 property?

Comment: I know this is 7 years later, but can you please explain what you mean?  I am experiencing this and having trouble understanding why this happens.  Why is an inner div NOT bound by the walls of the outer div?

Answer (score 1):

What helped me with the same problem is:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert from `margin` to `padding`, as inner space of element, and assign to **#outer**.

Then, the result will appear as your expect.

```css
#outer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}
#inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```